# Argument problems when creating rectangles using converted float

Tags: c#, parameters, xna

small issues when trying to create a rectangle using an int which has been converted from a float.

```
 CafBar.Position = new Vector2(30, 10);
 int CafLvlRound = (int)Math.Round(Player.CafLvl);
 CafRectangle = new Rectangle(CafBar.Position.X, CafBar.Position.Y, CafLvlRound, CafBar.Size.Height);
```

My problem is that when I use "CafLvlRound" as the third parameter, I get two errors saying that CafBar.Position.X and CafBar.Position.Y are floats and need to be converted to integers, when they are clearly assigned integers of 30 and 10? Then when I remove the third parameter, the errors disappear.

Anyone have any idea how to fix this or work around it?

Comment: I'm curious how _Then when I remove the third parameter, the errors disappear_ is true...

Comment: `I get two errors` what's the second?

Comment: 1st: CafBar.Position.X is float and needs to be int
2nd: The same as 1st error except with CafBar.Position.Y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CafBar.Position.X` and `CafBar.Position.Y` are floats and you know that both those values can be cast to int

So,

```
  CafRectangle = new Rectangle((int)CafBar.Position.X, (int)CafBar.Position.Y, CafLvlRound, CafBar.Size.Height);
```

Comment: Ah, thankyou! I'm pretty new to this so I'll remember casting for the future

Answer (score 1):

Vector2's only hold floats.  30 and 10 are integers, but the Vector2 constructor implictly casts them to floats.  Rectangles have 4 integer arguments, so each of them must be integers. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.rectangle.rectangle.aspx

Comment: `30 and 10 are floats, as well as integers` wat

Answer (score 1):

You should put `(int)value` when you need to convert to int and `(float)value` when you need to convert to float.

Comment: Thanks, I'll use this for the future!

Answer (score 1):

The [Vector2 constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb195795.aspx) *clearly* takes 2 floats as parameters, so what you are passing are going to be interpreted as floats, not ints.

If you look at the [X](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.vector2.x.aspx) and [Y](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.vector2.y.aspx) fields, as well, they're both clearly floats.

RTFM, man. It's your friend. You should change your code to work with floats in this context rather than converting back and forth from ints.